# How to filter a black image to 100% CMYK

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have an image I'm trying to prepare and am having difficulty changing the black #00000 to an absolute CMYK 100% black. I've tried a few filters and even paint bucketing the image, but I think I'm missing a setting for CMYK percentages and just using the color swatches. I've attached the file below, I'm coming from illustrator so this is a little new to me.

PSD file
https://we.tl/t-X2i3bOqPu9

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, since you need only one black channel, I would simply turn the image mode into greyscale. You should end up with a 100% black and depending on what you want to do with it, you could be good to go.

In case you had other colors than just black and want to convert into CMYK, you need to convert to a custom CMYK profile and adjust the black to maximum.
Not sure what are the commands called in English, so please have a look at the gif below:

[image]

Comment: Much appreciated, this got me where I needed to go!

Answer (score 3):

Take your original RGB image, convert to greyscale, Select all > copy > go to CMYK document > switch to black channel, paste special "paste in place"